# Azure Function .Net 5 Using ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-5

I'm using  .net 5 azure function with ServiceBusTrigger. In previous versin. I was using a parametr MessageReceiver to tell azure that I compleated task. For that I used

```cs
await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
```

My problem is that i new version (.net5) unlike the previous version (.net core 3.1) is param in string (json) not in object (maybe it's the error but I don't know which object to use, object I tried was Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver).

But now i do not have the object so i can not call the method.

Does someone knows the answer? Thak you for your time.

Example of my code:

```cs
Function("TasksFunction")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("queue", Connection = "ConnectionString")] string message, string id, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    try
    {
        await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
        await DoWorkAsync(messageReceiver, message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.LogCritical(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind your message to [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message?view=azure-dotnet) type instead of string

```
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("queue", Connection = "ConnectionString")] Message  message, string id, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, FunctionContext executionContext)
```

Message has [property SystemPropertiesCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.systempropertiescollection?view=azure-dotnet)  and use `message.SystemProperties.LockToken`